# Display all table A records which are not in table B using mysql joins concept

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A records are

```
id | email 
1  | abc@abc.com
2  | xyx@xy.com
3  | kkdk@kk.com
4  | 333@abc.com
```

Table B records are

```
id | email
1  | abc@abc.com
3  | kkdk@kk.com
```

Now result should be

```
id | email
2  | xyx@xy.com
4  | 333@abc.com
```

How to do this using joins ?

Comment: I have acheived the result using select id from tableA where id is not in (select id from tableB);

Comment: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, plainly, this question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
SELECT 
t1.*
FROM tableA as t1
LEFT JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.email=t2.email
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I tried like this select * from tableA left outer join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id; but it was showing all records in table A . All the difference is where condition

Comment: remember you need to join with the proper columns between tables

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct(a.id), a.email from table1 a inner join table2 b
on a.id not in (select id from table2)
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f18a/5)

Comment: I don't see why that would be better than the original post; in fact, it seems to be an antipattern.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

Try a left join and check where tableB id is null.

```
select tableA.* from tableA left join tableB on tableA.email = tableB.email
where tableB.id is null
```